# In Spring, is there a way to inject a class that does not have a @Component or only uses javax annotations?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a library that can use `javax.inject` annotations but must not be coupled to `Spring`, as it's used by both a `Spring` application and an application using `Guice`.

Other that creating an `@Bean` 'provider' in the `@Configuration`, is there a way to get `Spring` to inject the class into `@Autowired`/`@Inject` fields?

Comment: You'll need to define it as a bean somewhere to get it into the spring IOC container for autowiring. To keep it uncoupled from Spring, the best way is as you said, use a `@Bean` annotated method in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: One way or another, you need a bean definition for it. Whether that is through `@Bean`, `@Component` scanning, XML `<bean>`, or some other way is up to you.

Comment: The alternatives I can think of are so painfully roundabout compared to just adding a simple `@Bean` (or `<bean>`) definition. You can always write your own component scanning implementation though.